# Mysql update query wont save writing from text area

Tags: mysql

I am having a problem, i can connect to my database but it wont save in database what i wrote in a text area. Every time i click update it saves as blank, if i write lalala in mysql directly and refresh the page where text area is i can see lalala in text area but if i replace the text lalala in text area for something else and click update, it deletes the previous text lalala and leaves the field blank. Heres my code:

----------------------------- File 1 ---------------------------------

```
    <?
    include("header.inc.php");

    $result5 = mysql_query("SELECT faq FROM `demo_a_faq`");
    $myrow5 = mysql_fetch_row($result5);

    $faq = $myrow5[0];

    ?>
    <?
    include("../templates/admin-header.txt");
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="faq2.php">
    <TABLE bgcolor="#FFFFFF" bordercolor="#000008" border="0" width="95%" align="center">
    <TR>
    <TD width="50%"><center><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">                      <b>Edit FAQ:</b><br><textarea name="faneu" type="text" cols="80" rows="25"><? echo "$faq";     ?></textarea></TD>
     </TR>
     </TABLE><br><br>
<center><input type="submit" value="Update"></form></center>
<?
include("../templates/admin-footer.txt");
?>
```

----------------------------- File 2 ---------------------------------

```
<?
include("header.inc.php");

$asl = "UPDATE `demo_a_faq` SET `faq` = '$faneu'";
$results = mysql_query($asl) or die(mysql_error());

?>
<?
include("../templates/admin-header.txt");
?>
<center><br><br><br><b>Updated!</b></center>
<?
include("../templates/admin-footer.txt");
?>
```

---

In header.inc.php i simply have the conection to database.

Can someone please tell me why it is not saving what i write in text area to database as it is driving me crazy.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
include("header.inc.php");

// Always escape variables used in SQL-queries to avoid SQL-injections.
$faneu = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['faneu']);

$asl = "UPDATE `demo_a_faq` SET `faq` = '$faneu'";
$results = mysql_query($asl) or die(mysql_error());

?>
<?
include("../templates/admin-header.txt");
?>
<center><br><br><br><b>Updated!</b></center>
<?
include("../templates/admin-footer.txt");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't POST your textarea value to "FILES 2".Be carefull.

Comment: Hi. May you tell me why you say "Be carefull" please as security is number one priority for my site and if there is something i am missing i would really appreciate you letting me know.